# Creating a database that all projects can use

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I was wondering if anyone can help - in my C# solution I have a project for my application front end, and a project for the server. I want to have a database that both server and client front end can use, any advice on how to do this?

Comment: Why access the database from your client directly. Shouldn't interaction with the database go via the server?

Comment: What do you mean by "both server and client can use"? Do you want to share the schema? Do you want to use the same engine in both cases? Do you want to keep then sinchronized?

Comment: What problems are you having?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx jumps to mind, though I would be VERY careful about letting client applications write directly to the database if you have a "server" as well. Clients should ask the server to write for them if you want to be more secure.